# C struct array segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, struct

I am making a game in c, and I get an error with a struct array which I have created.

```
typedef struct{
    int type, level, x, y, w, h;
} Tile;

Tile *map[256];
Tile *t;
t->type = 0;
t->level = 0;
t->x = 0;
t->y = 0;
t->w = 0;
t->h = 0;
map[0] = t;
```

Once compiled, the program prints:
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Sure it does. You define pointers but do not point them to valid objects.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please read about memory allocation, pointers and C in general. No offence, but just reading a good C book will help you much more than a simple comment and any specific answer will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a pointer does not automatically make that pointer to point to a valid memory location. A pointer, which is not allocated memory, is called as uninitialized pointer and cannot (*shall we say, should not?*) be de-referenced.

In your code,

```
t->type = 0;
```

and so on, you're de-referencing `t` which is not allocated memory. Hence, by de-referencing an unitialized pointer, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The segmentation fault is one of the many side-effects of the UB.

Solution: You need to allocate memory to `t` before you can actually dereference it. Maybe you can have a look at [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family of functions to get the memory allocation done.

Comment: ok, so how do I do that then?

Comment: @DJGee as I said, you need to allocate memory to the pointer first.

Comment: @DJGee Definitely need to follow Olaf's advice.

Comment: Note: there is no such thing as "allocating memory for a pointer", only "allocating memory" and making a pointer point to that memory.

Comment: @immibis Please explain that. What exactly you find wrong there.

Comment: @immibis Modified the wordings. Thanks for the comment. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @DJGee Please try to [Understand This](http://ideone.com/zTrS1B).

Comment: @Michi I mean there is no such thing as "allocating memory for a pointer"; I'm not sure what's not to understand... What do you mean when you say "allocating memory for a pointer"? Allocated memory just exists; it's entirely up to you how you want to point to it.

Comment: @immibis Your point is the same like speaking about `Stack` or `Heap`, but  "There is no stack and Heap". So why should we argue on that?

Comment: @Michi More like if someone says "Classes can be allocated on the stack or heap" (in C++) and I say "No, *objects* (or *instances*) can be allocated on the stack or heap".

Comment: @immibis Yes, but there is no such thing as `Stack` or `Heap` in `C`.

Comment: @Michi Yeah, but you also don't get anything *wrong* if you decide to call objects with automatic storage duration "stack-allocated". Whereas the "allocate memory to a pointer" idea leads to questions like "How do I move allocated memory to a different pointer?" and code like `char *p = malloc(...); p = "Hello"; puts(p); free(p);`

Comment: @immibis When `p` points to that `string literal` you loose the track of the memory alocated for `p`. This makes `free` to try to dealocate `p`, but `p` points somewhere else now.

Comment: @Michi I know why it's wrong. People who think malloc "allocates memory to a pointer" usually don't. After all, "how can p hold a string if it doesn't have any memory allocated"?

Comment: @immibis There is no such thing like `string` in `C`, but if we speak about that, well that `string` is set aside in memory (read-only) and `p` points to that location. I give up now, Good night :D.

Comment: @Michi **I know perfectly well why it doesn't work.** I was trying to explain why believing "malloc allocates memory to a pointer" causes **new C programmers** to believe things that are wrong.